# XML descendents - Get values based on length

Tags: c#, xml

Hi I have an xml file as below.

```xml
<findAddressCoordinatesList>
    <findAddressCoordinatesListItem>
        <id>1</id>
        <description>Electricity Sub Station 1M From ...</description>
    </findAddressCoordinatesListItem>
    <findAddressCoordinatesListItem>
        <id>2</id>
        <description>Beauchamp House, Greyfriars Road, ...</description>
    </findAddressCoordinatesListItem>
</findAddressCoordinatesList>
```

I want to create a list of addresses from the description, but the description can be of variable length. 
I think I may need to split the description using delimiter comma and get array length, then assign the individual field values based on the length.

Any suggestions what's the best way to do this?

```cs
XDocument xmldocLinq = XDocument.Parse(Xmlstring);
List<Address> AddressList = (from info in xmldocLinq.Descendants("findAddressCoordinatesListItem")

    select new Address
    {                                   
        Id = int.Parse(info.Element("Id").Value), 
        Number = (info.Element("description").Value.ToString().Split(',')[len -5]) //only if not null
        Building = info.Element("description").Value.ToString().Split(',')[len -4], //only if not null
        Street = info.Element("description").Value.ToString().Split(',')[len -3],
        Town = info.Element("description").Value.ToString().Split(',')[len -2], 
        Postcode = info.Element("description").Value.ToString().Split(',')[len -1],  
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already know what and all the tags will be there in description, it's better to keep those tags inside description.

Example,

```
<description>
   <number> ## </umber>
   <building> XYZ </building>
   <street> XXX </street>
   <town> YYY </town>
   <postcode> #### </postcode>
</description>
```

I guess this is the best way to write address.

PS : you can access those elements in loop as well

Comment: The xml is built from a http response to an external service, and does not contain the individual fields but only description. I need to separate the individual fields and build an address list.